# Using IDENTITY while creating table

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment, identity

I am learning SQL and totally new to this world. What I have learnt / read about using identity is: it is used to create an identity column with Seed and increment value ~ Identity (Seed, increment). However going through some sample database available on net, I came across this table creation script:

```
create table Customer 
(
    Id                   int                  identity,
    FirstName            nvarchar(40)         not null,
    LastName             nvarchar(40)         not null,
    City                 nvarchar(40)         null,
    Country              nvarchar(40)         null,
    Phone                nvarchar(20)         null,
    constraint PK_CUSTOMER primary key (Id)
)
go
```

I tried creating table with this code and it was successful.

Can someone explain why `IDENTITY` here does not have seed and increment values? When should we use it like this (without seed and increment values) ?

TIA

Comment: IDENTITY has default seed and increment value are 1 respectively,

Comment: In other words sql server does some stuff for you.

Answer (score 2):

When you use -->  Id int identity

It is equivalent to --->  Id int identity(1,1)

So the first value will be inserted into table with Id = 1 and incremented by 1 for next row. so this is the default value for identity if nothing is specified. In case if you want to start your Id with some specific number, for ex -  you want to create customerId column which should have at least 5 digit id than you have to define the column as ---> CustomerId int identity(10000 ,1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer .this was helpful .